# Flutter Android App does not work only on my device throws NullPointerException: Display.getRefreshRate()

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem; I created a new flutter project from Android Studio(just new project-no addition). This app does not work only with my device(my device is a custom Android) but works with other devices and emulator, devices and emulators are Android 9.

Throws this exception:

```
2023-08-11 16:17:42.710 2811-2811/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 2811
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.Display.getRefreshRate()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2944)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3079)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.Display.getRefreshRate()' on a null object reference
    at io.flutter.view.f.f(Unknown Source:45)
    at l.d.k(Unknown Source:48)
    at l.d.j(Unknown Source:5)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.d.<init>(Unknown Source:28)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.g.H(Unknown Source:172)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.g.q(Unknown Source:7)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.onCreate(Unknown Source:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
```

Comment: Android device has the latest firmware and updates. Sometimes, issues related to display properties or system components can be resolved through updates.

Comment: Hi, there is no way to update Android version of the device. Device has a custom Android.